# Validating XML against DTD in which elements appears in random order

Tags: xml, dtd

```
<!ELEMENT myxml (first,second,third)>
<!ELEMENT first (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT second (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT third (#PCDATA)>
```

The DTD above restricts the child element (first, second and third) to be in the same order in the XML. Is there any way that this DTD can validate to the XML in which the elements are compulsory but can appear in any order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky when you need exactly one of each child elements. This is the only way I can think of and it's not very pretty. It works though...

```
<!ELEMENT myxml ( 
                 (first,second,third)|
                 (first,third,second)|
                 (second,first,third)|
                 (second,third,first)|
                 (third,first,second)|
                 (third,second,first)
                )>
<!ELEMENT first (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT second (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT third (#PCDATA)>
```

Basically I'm specifying every possible combination of exactly one `first`, `second`, and `third` elements.

Here's an example instance. `first`, `second`, and `third` can be in any order, but they each must occur exactly one time.

```
<!DOCTYPE myxml [
<!ELEMENT myxml ( 
                 (first,second,third)|
                 (first,third,second)|
                 (second,first,third)|
                 (second,third,first)|
                 (third,first,second)|
                 (third,second,first)
                )>
<!ELEMENT first (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT second (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT third (#PCDATA)>
]>
<myxml>
  <third></third>
  <first></first>
  <second></second>
</myxml>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!ELEMENT myxml (first|second|third)*>
<!ELEMENT first (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT second (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT third (#PCDATA)>
```

The above isn't very useful, though. You'd be more likely to want to require at least one child, like this:

```
<!ELEMENT myxml (first|second|third)+>
<!ELEMENT first (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT second (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT third (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: The only problem with using the `+` occurrence indicator is that you are specifying one or more of any of the child elements. This means that you could have something like 2 `second` elements and nothing else. I think the OP wants to be sure that each element is present and only occurs once.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that all the elements were compulsory. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries. I was just sayin' ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In XML DTDs, there is no elegant way to specify this constraint. You can do as @DevNull suggests; it is legal, but the technique becomes unwieldy when the number of elements is large.

If this had been about an SGML DTD, then you could have used the [`&` (AND) connector](http://www.xmlgrrl.com/publications/DSDTD/apa.html#elemdecls). But that is one of the features that was [removed](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-sgml-xml.html) when XML was created.